# jQuery object methods fails when using live/on

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with selector by `#` inside `live()` or `on()` callback.

```
$(document).on('click',".dfield_span_after", function(event) {
    var in_id = $(this).attr('data-in_id');
    var field = $('#'+in_id) // this line
    field.show();
}
```

`field.show()` doesn't work at all, however selecting like this:

```
var field = $('[id='+in_id+']')
```

works fine.

Is it a jQuery problem (several versions were used) or is it something I've done wrong?

UPDATE:
If it may help, this thing doesn't work in such situation. I have a page with some elements that interact like shown in code. This code works fine just before I click a link, that produces some elements by AJAX and displays it in popup. And elements in popup work bad, the rest of page is still fine.

Thanks

Comment: Something's wrong here `var in_id = $(this).attr('data-in_id');`

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/59ayt/

Comment: Read the update please, I forgot to mention that id doesn't work only after ajax-generated content. And everything but `field.show()` seems fine, because, for example `console.log(field)` gives me the exact element that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[id=theid]` works and `#theid` doesn't, that typically means you have duplicate ID's on your page. ID's must be unique.

**Edit** on comments:

So, if you do this:

```
$(document).on('click',".dfield_span_after", function(event) {
    var in_id = $(this).attr('data-in_id');
    var field = $('#'+in_id) // this line
    field.show();
    alert(field.length);
    alert($("[id="+in_id+"]").length);
}
```

You get two alerts of `1`?

Comment: Yes, it could be like this, but I checked with crome developer there is only one (!) `id` like this. I just copied `data-in_id` value and searched for it, and get only one match — needed element's `id`. Don't know, why can't I see another match the `data-in_id` attribute itself? And yes, they are equal, I checked it.

Comment: look for elements that have a duplicate id="in_id" where in_id is the actual value. This is a good test: `alert($("[id=" + in_id + "]").length);` It should alert `1` if there are no duplicates.

Comment: Kevin, I've already checked it, it is 1. And I can see on console this element selected by `$("#"+in_id)` but I can't do **anything** to it! Can't change attributes, can't show, can't hide, It just does nothing. But we sould keep in mind that this behaviour happens only on ajax-generated elements

Comment: It's pretty strange, I get first alert with '1' and the second with '2' =) But the second one works fine with events.

Comment: If the second alerts 2, you definitely have duplicate id's. The first one should correctly always alert 1 because document.getElementById will always return 1 or no elements.

Comment: Kevin, that is true.. But now I know that facebox, that handled the popup, somehow made this duplicates. Thank you! The problem is solved!